# Answering duplicate questions without flag privilege

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, old-questions

While writing an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54869292/how-to-design-linear-dynamic-programming-algorithm-for-shortest-path), I found an [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775947/directed-graph-linear-algorithm/54902174#54902174) that is, in essence, identical. Since this makes the newer question a duplicate of the older one, I figured the right thing to do is answer the original question (even though this decreases the chance of my answer being accepted).

However, since I also want to point the poster of the newer version of the question to my answer, I'd like to either flag the new question as a duplicate or leave a comment; however, I do not have enough reputation for either. What's the right thing to do for me here?

Comment: When you answer the newer question, then don't just copy your old answer. And other than that, there is not much you can do. So contribute on other posts until to get the missing reputation points.

Comment: Hmm... you should be able to flag as a dupe at 15 rep...

Comment: Well yes, things have gone well :) My answer on the old question has been upvoted. However, at the point of asking my question, it might also have happened my answer gets "lost" and I wouldn't have been able to inform the poster of the duplicate that his question now has an answer